# Text appearing on top whenever I open terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, android, eclipse

Whenever I open my terminal I get this text at the top:

```
bash: export: `PATH-/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ethiojob/workspace/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `PATH-/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ethiojob/workspace/Android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools': not a valid identifier
```

I have downloaded and installed the Android ADT plugin to use with Eclipse, and I believe this has something to do with it. If there is anything to be fixed, how do I fix it? Otherwise how do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably edited `~/.bashrc` and updated your `PATH`, but instead of writing `PATH=...`, wrote `PATH-...`. Change the hyphen to `=` and it should be fixed.